# Image PNG Rewriter: Как сжать PNG?

Tags: изображения, png, perl

Добрый день!

Есть один проект на Perl, называется [Image-PNG-Rewriter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-PNG-Rewriter/). Суть работы заключается в сжатии PNG использую для этого 7-zip.

Все нужные компоненты установил, но вот как пользоваться, так и не понял, подскажите, как мне сжать PNG, используя Image PNG Rewriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `perldoc Image::PNG::Rewriter`
2. [Тык мышой](http://search.cpan.org/~bjoern/Image-PNG-Rewriter-0.9/lib/Image/PNG/Rewriter.pm) (то же самое откроется)

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно? Создать объект при помощи new(), список параметров в документации расписан. Метод as_png возвращает данные PNG.

Comment: вы не могли бы написать пример использования Image::PNG::Rewriter и и как мне управлять параметрами Pass, FastBytes, Cycles

Comment: http://www.sourcepod.com/mwxolv32-10672

Набросал вслепую, надеюсь, не накосячил :)

Comment: спасибо большое что откликнулись на мою просьбу.

Вы не подскажите, а как пользоваться скриптом?
пробовал так perl png.pl a.png b.png, но у меня не получилось
выдает 
read() on closed filehandle $h at C:/Perl/site/lib/Image/PNG/Rewriter.pm line 45
.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at C:/Perl/site/lib/Image/PNG/Rewr
iter.pm line 45.
Died at C:/Perl/site/lib/Image/PNG/Rewriter.pm line 45.

Comment: Вообще-то там входной файл в коде прописан, а выход - stdout. Ну вот для 2 аргументов в комстроке: http://www.sourcepod.com/zpqnqj05-10674

Comment: код сам работает, но не сжимает. Странно как-то.
Такой вопрос а вы http://search.cpan.org/~bjoern/Compress-Deflate7-1.0/ устанавливали, и если да, то как?
у меня с ним были проблемы, устанавливал под windows.
если не трудно давайте перенесем наш разговор на почту lorents17@mail.ru

Comment: Не ставил, да и нет её в windows-репозитории. А пережать png - задача нетривиальная, здесь нужен подбор параметров (дельта-фильтры etc) для каждого конкретного случая. Если что и справляется, да и то не всегда, то это OptiPNG, например: http://optipng.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Я отлично разбираюсь в сжатии PNG http://habrahabr.ru/post/119009/ (моя статья).
у меня свой проект есть даже http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=4&topic=4263
суть не в этом, я хочу научиться использовать Image PNG Rewriter под винду

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MImage::PNG::Rewriter -e 'print Image::PNG::Rewriter->new(handle => \*STDIN)->as_png'
```

Comment: можно, пожалуйста, поподробнее.
а лучше скрипт?

Comment: Вот:    

    # perl -MImage::PNG::Rewriter -e 'print Image::PNG::Rewriter->new(handle => \*STDIN)->as_png' < a.png > b.png
    # ls -l *.png
    -rw-r--r--. 1 arto users 153474 Sep  9 22:07 a.png
    -rw-r--r--. 1 arto users 153426 Sep  9 22:07 b.png
    #

Comment: у меня выдает Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

кстати у вас http://search.cpan.org/~bjoern/Compress-Deflate7-1.0/ нормально установился? у меня с ним были проблемы.

Хочу обяснить ситуацию, я знаю Perl очень, очень плохо, но мне надо заставить работать Image::PNG::Rewriter

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте онлайн сжималку [tinyPNG](http://highload.com.ua/post/TinyPNG+-+%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+PNG) - там есть API. Для локального сжатия также советую посмотреть на [OptiPNG](http://highload.com.ua/post/OptiPNG+-+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+PNG+%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (консольная утилити).